# How to manually construct the following functional statement

Tags: kdb

I need to create a functional statement for the following expression

```
select from table where not any venue like/:("tst1";tst2)
```

This is what I have now:

```
(enlist(~:;(any;((/:;like);`venue;(enlist;a)))))
```

where a can be either `"tst1"` or `("tst1";tst2)`

This is the issue. I want to pass that `a` as a parameter, but it does not work. 
The line should look like:

```
(enlist(~:;(any;((/:;like);`venue;(enlist;"tst1";"tst2")))))
```

Anyone has any suggestions. I'm a bit stuck .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly let's use `parse` to see the tree:

```
q)parse "select from table where not any venue like/:(\"tst1\";\"tst2\")"
?
`table
,,(~:;(max$["b"];((/:;like);`venue;(enlist;"tst1";"tst2"))))
0b
()
```

Next, let's use the `enlist,` trick to build the element list in your like statement

```
q)0N!enlist,`a`b;
(enlist;`a;`b)

// let's define 'a' and use the same method
q)a:("tst1";"tst2")
q)enlist,a
enlist
"tst1"
"tst2"
q)0N!enlist,a;
(enlist;"tst1";"tst2")
```

Let's piece it together

```
// define table
q)table:([]venue:("tst1";"tst2";"tst3"))
q)?[`table;enlist(not;(any;((/:;like);`venue;enlist,a)));0b;()]
venue
------
"tst3"
```

As a note, you are not using any sort of regex there, so you'd be better off using direct matching:

```
q)select from table where not ([]venue) in ([]venue:a)
venue
------
"tst3"

// or a function to help you
q)f:{[lst] select from table where not ([]venue) in ([]venue:lst)}
q)f[a]
venue
------
"tst3"
```

HTH, Sean

Comment: hi. please explain this `enlist,a`. What is that about. it's the first time i see it and yes your solution works. so all I had to do was to create a list in which one of the elements is enlist. wow. Thanks

Comment: `enlist,a` is simply joining a function with another variable. You can do the same with `{x*x},a`. They need to be joined to create the given parse tree structure. As to why an `enlist` is required, this is due to how `/:` is handled, i.t., `parse "sym foo/: (x;y;z)"`